JavaFX modify object of other FXML file?
I have one controller class for 2 windows (made with SceneBuilder in JavaFX).
When the second window gets opened, I want to modify the ScrollPane in the first window by pressing on a button in the second window. I thought this would work since the ScrollPane is in the same controller class, but I'm getting a null pointer.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.setFitToWidth(boolean)" because "this.ScrollingContainer" is null

package application;


import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainSceneController {
    

    @FXML
     private AnchorPane anchorPane;

    @FXML
    private Label CurrentLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button NewTaskButton;
    
    @FXML
    private DatePicker DatePicker;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane ScrollingContainer;

    @FXML
    private Button todayBTN;
    
    
    
    
    @FXML
    private Button CancelButton;

    @FXML
    private MenuButton CategoryButton;
    
    
    
 
    @FXML
    private Button ConfirmButton;

    @FXML
    private TextField DateField;

    @FXML
    private TextField DetailsField;

    @FXML
    private TextField TitleField;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane2;
    
    Stage newWindow;
    
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String category;
    private String date;
    boolean completed = false;
   
    
    private boolean hasScrollPane() {
        if (anchorPane != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    @FXML
    void CancelTaskActivated(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void ConfirmButtonActivated(ActionEvent event) {
        title = TitleField.getText();
         description = DetailsField.getText();
         
         
 if (title != null && category != null && date != null) {
     Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
     Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
     stage.close();
     CardComponent newCard = new CardComponent(title, description, category, date);
     FillPane(newCard);
 }
    }
   
private void FillPane(CardComponent newCard) {
    cardContainer.setPadding(new Insets(10));
     VBox card = newCard.getCard();
        cardContainer.getChildren().add(card);
        
        ScrollingContainer.setFitToWidth(true);
        ScrollingContainer.setFitToHeight(true);
        ScrollingContainer.setContent(cardContainer);
}
    VBox cardContainer = new VBox(10);
    public void initialize() {
        if (hasScrollPane()) {
             FillScrollPane();
        } else {
            
         MenuItem Item1 = new MenuItem("");
            MenuItem Item2 = new MenuItem("");
            MenuItem Item3 = new MenuItem("");
            MenuItem Item4 = new MenuItem("");
            CategoryButton.getItems().removeAll();
        CategoryButton.getItems().addAll(Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4);
        Item1.setOnAction(e -> CategoryButton.setText(""));
        category = "";
        
        Item2.setOnAction(e -> CategoryButton.setText(""));
        category = "";
        
        Item3.setOnAction(e -> CategoryButton.setText(""));
        category = "";
        
        Item4.setOnAction(e -> CategoryButton.setText(""));
        category = "";
        
        
            
      
    
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public void openTaskWindow(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
         FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CreateTask.fxml"));
         Parent newWindowRoot = loader.load();
      
         newWindow = new Stage(); 
         newWindow.setTitle("New Window");
         newWindow.setScene(new Scene(newWindowRoot));
         newWindow.show();
    }

    
    
    
   @FXML
    void NewTaskActivated(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
openTaskWindow(event);
    }

    
    

}


"I have one controller class for 2 windows". Don't. Create a different controller class for each FXML file.
